# Did these quotes really originate from Jerry Maguire?

Tags: etymology, phrases, phrase-origin

I just finished watching [Jerry Maguire (1996)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Maguire), and noticed the sheer amount of idioms in it that it apparently coined:

> It notably spawned a large number of catch phrases into popular culture, most prominently "Show me the money!" and "You had me at 'Hello'." (which were deemed the 25th and 52nd most memorable American movie quotations of all time, respectively in a 2005 survey by the American Film Institute) It also included "You complete me.", "Help me help you.", and other quotations.

But that claim on Wikipedia is only partially sourced, and the quotes seem so ubiquitous and cliched nowadays that they seem like they must be older than 1996. I know there are plenty of sources for these claims, including the AFI for the two quotes that the article states, but it's also not unlikely that all of these sources are just parroting a single misinformed source.

Have any of these quotes ever been attested to earlier than the movie, or did Jerry Maguire really coin them all? To be clear, I'm asking about the four quotes claimed on the Wikipedia page:

> You complete me
> Help me help you
> You had me at "Hello"
> Show me the money

Comment: As a catchphrase, *Show me the money* is strictly from the film. Doesn't mean the words were never used in life before that.

Comment: @YosefBaskin If a quote has been attested to publicly since before the film, then it can't be "strictly from the film".

Comment: What research have you already done? Please let us know in order to demonstrate that you've made some effort and also so that we don't wastefully duplicate your work.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I've done just enough research to know there are plenty of sources for this information, as mentioned in the question, but I can't be sure that they're reliable and I'm looking for something more definitive., as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Someone might have said "you complete me" before but if nobody noticed, does it matter? Are you looking for popular texts, ephemeral texts, private texts? It's clear the film popularised them but it didn't invent words.

Comment: This looks like four questions, not one.

Comment: @StuartF As stated above: *if a quote has been attested to **publicly***... I'm looking for the first attestations in whatever *public* record they exist in. This is common sense and obvious hair-splitting for the sake of closing the question in typical SE fashion; any record that can be looked up is inherently public - even if the information existed in a private form, we wouldn't know about it.

Comment: [This Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=show+me+the+money%2Cyou+complete+me%2Chelp+me+help+you%2Cyou+had+me+at+hello&year_start=1820&year_end=1994&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows the frequency of matches for the four word strings across the period 1820–1994 (the year before the movie was released). As you can see, the only one that flatlines is "You had me at hello" So all the others had at least some life before _Jerry Maguire_. "Show me the money," for example occurs in Tennessee Williams's _Summer and Smoke_ (1948). "You complete me" appears in Edmond Rostand's ...

Comment: ... _Cyrano de Bergerac_ (1898) in the form "Will you complete me, and let me complete you?" And "Help me help you" (despite a number of false positives unrelated to the words as a standalone phrase), appears in a letter submitted as an exhibit in a U.S. 1911 Congressional hearing in the form "all I ask of you is to help me help you."

Comment: @SvenYargs that sounds like an answer

Comment: These are all common American expressions, except for: You complete me. And too much for one question, I agree with Laurel.

Comment: @SvenYargs Thanks for being the only one so far to understood what I was asking for. If you could put that into an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @SvenYargs One clarification that I think is important and worth including in the answer - is "show me the money" in Summer and Smoke used in the same sense as it is in Jerry Maguire, or is it used literally? I think that's probably the only one of these quotes that could also be used in a literal sense.

Comment: Here is the (literal) context for "Show me the money" in _Summer and Smoke_: "GONZALES: ... I don't have money to buy a string of gold bead so next day I go for a ride up to Eagle Pass and I walk in a dry good store and I say to the man: 'Please give me a string a gold bead.' He say: '**Show me the money**,' and I say: 'Here is the money!' And I reach down to my belt and I pull out—not the money—but this! [_He pulls out a revolver._]" I don't have time to write up a formal and complete answer today, but if the question is still open later in the week I will try to put one together.